# Regex for Redirection problems (Cherokee Web Server)

Tags: regex, redirect, cherokee

I'm having a real problem with this because I just can't get my head around regexes.

I'm using Cherokee Web Server and I'm trying to use a regex to perform a redirection.

I need to get the following url (for example)

```
/parts/tr/accessories/tyres
```

to the controller like this

```
index.php?page=parts&catalogue=tr&category=accessories&subcategory=tyres
```

can somebody help me please!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with Cherokee, but the regex would be:

```
([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)
```

and replacement pattern would look like:

```
index.php?page=$1&catalogue=$2&category=$3&subcategory=$4
```